Why does Gandalf question Thorin after he had found the note?
Why does Gandalf question Thorin about their orc hunters, AFTER he had already found a note in black speech offering payment for Thorin's head and showing him this in the tavern.
Gandalf and Balin also share a look in regards to Azog's status of "death".
If Gandalf knows Azog is alive and that Azog is after Thorin, why the question?
A reward offered for Thorin's head in black speech was discovered by Gandalf himself.
Shouldn't he know who's hunting them. Is there something I'm missing?

Note: this is a movie question. Gandalf questioning Thorin happens in An Unexpected Journey (when they meet Radagast), while Gandalf meeting Thorin at Bree is a flashback at the beginning of The Desolation of Smaug. IIRC nothing of this sort is in the book.

@lfurini The narrative of Gandalf meeting Thorin at Bree is published in Unfinished Tales. It was originally written during the drafting of the LotR Appendices, was not finished and more or less for reasons of space. There are two versions of the story, though Christopher only gives one in full. Bree of course hadn't been invented when Tolkien wrote The Hobbit!

*cut, more or less for reasons of space

@DavidRoberts The scene as written is quite different from the movie version, though. There's no indication that anyone is after Thorin (the goblins being relatively indifferent until after the Great Goblin is killed and Sauron having gotten what he wanted--Thráin's ring--long before). Gandalf simply uses Thorin's desire to regain Erebor as a catalyst for doing something about Smaug before Sauron could make use of him.

@chepner I didn't claim otherwise. I merely pointed out the source of inspiration for the meeting scene.
